# How does curvature do that?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In his book "Riemannian geometry" Do Carmo said

> The curvature measures the amount that a riemannian manifold deviates from being euclidean

**My question is**
How does the curvature measure this amount? In other words, why the value and sign of curvature describe the topography of the manifold?

Comment: There are a lot of non-trivial manifolds with zero curvature. It's not a good way of thinking about curvature.

Comment: So what do you suggest?@user40276

Comment: You can think as a measure of an infinitesimal holonomy. Or as a think that shows you the sectional curvature (which is more intuitive). Actually you compute sectional curvature by "extending" the gauss curvature (see Lee's book on riemmanian geometry)

Comment: A riemannian manifold with zero curvature is locally isometric to euclidean space, so it is a very good way to think about curvature. The sign of the curvature tells you many things about deviations from euclidean space. For example, the Gauss-Bonnet formula says that the sum of angles in a triangle (the sides are geodesics) is 180 + integral of curvature over  the triangle. So in positive curvature triangles are plump, in negative curvature they are all skinny with sharp vertices...

Comment: @user40276 I didn't have any back ground in holonomy, and my qyestion is how not what does it mean?

Comment: @GilBor my question why riemannian manifolds with zero curvature is locally isometric to euclidean space, what does the curvature do to say this conclusion. The rule $d=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$ uses a right angle triangle and Pythagorean thearem to get the distance between two points, so we understand it. Similarly why "The sign of the curvature tells you many things about deviations from euclidean space" ???? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not difficult to prove that it's locally isometric to the euclidean space. You just have to know the "formula" of the curvature when you change the coordinates and use the connection form to solve a differential equation using  Poincaré's lemma.

Comment: @user40276 This is true but it is not answer of my question. The geodesic equation for example $\nabla_TT=0$ says the speed of the curve is constant i.e. the equation measures the change of the tangent field along the geodesic so when the left side is zero we say that the curve have a constant speed. My question is similarly how and what does the curvature measure so we say that its value has a specific indication?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best website I found that describes it rigorously is http://www.kjm.pmf.kg.ac.rs/pub/12617190662534_13.pdf. In that website it simplifies to taking an associated curve in the euclidean plane and seeing how much 'inverse distance'it deviates from a curve, that's why derivatives are used extensively.